# android-reverse geocoding-Google Map API (geocoding)

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing android app where I use google reverse geocoding API webservice  in the user side, for the user to read his address in text format.
 `HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
                            + lat + "," + lng + "&sensor=true");`

I have the following three questions:

1-Do I have to use a map in my app?, as I'm only displaying the location in text to User and I don't want a map in my app?
https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1
"(h) No Use of Content without a Google Map. You must not use or display the Content without a corresponding Google map, unless you are explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps APIs Documentation"

2-is it a must that I include API key at app side part of calling the webservice?

3-am I expected to establish enterprise agreement with Google, and get client_ID and include it in the request sent by the end user?
https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1

Answer (score 0):

To answer the questions:

1) I think you can use this without using the maps, for, in the API doc it said:

> The Google Geocoding API provides a direct way to access a these services via an HTTP request.
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Geocoding

2) You need an API key for using the service, even it works without using one (not recommended). Refer to this section for more information.

> All Maps API applications* should load the Maps API using an API key. Using an API key enables you to monitor your application's Maps API usage, and ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary. 
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

3) for client_id, I think you don't need to unless you have to..
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/

Comment: I think I would have to disagree with both 1 and 2.  The top level terms of service says "You must not use or display the Content without a corresponding Google map, unless you are explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps APIs Documentation."  I don't see anywhere in the geocoding documentation that EXPLICITLY says you can use it without a map.  And as for 2, it says you "should" use an API key, not must.  Of course Google wants you to use one, so they can track you.  But I don't believe the terms of service require it, and the API certainly doesn't.

Comment: I would argue that what google meant for #1 is to not to use their API and populate the result on other maps. I mean, if there are other requirements, they would say it out loud like this one. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#LogoRequirements

Comment: and for #2, yes, it will work without the key right now, but who knows when they will enforce the API key requirement.... yup, it is not a must, but, don't be evil.

Comment: For number 1, why do you think it means something other than what it states? Or do you see somewhere in the geocoding documentation that it explicitly allows geocoding and then not displaying the results on a Google map?  For number 2, yes it is possible they'll require it in the future, but they give notice about things like that.  And I see nothing evil about doing something both the technical interface and terms of service permit.